# How to indicate end of path variable in postman

Tags: postman

I am trying to test some requests with Postman to the [Open Library Covers API](https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/covers) and I cannot find a proper way to send my params.

According to the docs, the request should be something like this:

```
http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/$key/$value-$size.jpg
```

I am configuring my `GET` request as follows:

```
http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/:key/:value-:size.jpg
```

I can properly fill the `key` path variable but unfortunately `:value-:size.jpg` is recognized as one unique variable. **How can I split it so that those are two variables `:value` and `:size`?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: still, don't understand the issue, sorry(

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to make postman understand that `:value` and `:size` are two different path variables @Vova

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet found a solution but a possible alternative.

If I configure the request as:

```
http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/{{key}}/{{value}}-{{size}}.jpg
```

I can then use the `Pre-req` to define the following assignments:

```
pm.variables.set('key', 'isbn');
pm.variables.set('value', '0385472579');
pm.variables.set('size', 'S');
```

This is not exactly what I was looking for, but it works.

Comment: This works but is not good for documentation. The problem with this solution is that the variables marked by "{{}}" do not appear in the "Path variables" table (tab "Params"). Only path variables marked by ":" will automatically appear there and you can then add a description that will be added by Postman to the collection's documentation page. I noted that even params preceded with // (e.g. the hostname) are not recognized as a variable.

Comment: A hint: instead of setting the values in the Pre-request Script, you can also set them as a Postman Environment variable.